# Collection.liquid in shopify to display on subcollections

Tags: shopify

When i click on Shop on top the menu it displays all collections in the website. Ideally it should display only Mens and Womens.

[image]

Is there any problem with the collection.liquid below

```
{% assign products_per_row = settings.collections_products_per_row %}
{% assign rows = settings.collections_rows %}
{% assign total_products = products_per_row | times: rows %}

{% paginate collection.products by total_products %}

<div class="section-header section-header--breadcrumb">
  {% include 'breadcrumb' %}

</div>

<header class="section-header section-header--large">
  <h1 class="section-header__title{% if settings.collections_tags_enable or settings.collections_sort_enable %} section-header__title--left{% endif %}">{{ collection.title }}</h1>
  {% if settings.collections_tags_enable or settings.collections_sort_enable %}
  <div class="section-header__link--right">
    {% if settings.collections_tags_enable %}
      {% include 'collection-tags' %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if settings.collections_sort_enable %}
      {% include 'collection-sorting' %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</header>
    {{  collection.id  }}
{% if collection.description != blank %}
  <div class="rte rte--header">
    {{ collection.description }}

  </div>
  <hr class="hr--clear hr--small">
{% endif %}

{% case products_per_row %}
  {% when '2' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium--one-half large--one-half' %}
  {% when '3' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium--one-third large--one-third' %}
  {% when '4' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium--one-half large--one-quarter' %}
  {% when '5' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium--one-half large--one-fifth' %}
{% endcase %}

<div class="grid-uniform grid-link__container">

  {% for product in collection.products %}

    {% include 'product-grid-item' %}

  {% else %}

    {% if shop.products_count == 0 %}
      {% unless emptyState %}
        {{ 'theme-onboarding.css' | global_asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
        {% assign emptyState = true %}
      {% endunless %}
ssss
      <div class="grid__item">
        <div class="helper-section">
          <div class="helper-note">
            <span class="helper-icon"></span>
            <h3>{{ 'home_page.onboarding.modal_title' | t }}</h3>
            <p>{{ 'home_page.onboarding.no_products_collection' | t }}</p>
            <p><a class="admin-btn-primary" href="/admin/products/new">{{ 'home_page.onboarding.add_product' | t }}</a></p>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-uniform helper-content">
            {% assign index = 1 %}
            {% for i in (1..8) %}
              {% case i %}
                {% when 7 %}
                  {% assign index = 1 %}
                {% when 8 %}
                  {% assign index = 2 %}
              {% endcase %}
              <div class="grid__item one-half large--one-quarter">
                <a href="/admin/products" class="grid-link">
                  <span class="grid-link__image grid-link__image--product">
                    <span class="grid-link__image-centered">
                      {% capture imageUrl %}//cdn.shopify.com/s/images/themes/product-{{ index }}.png{% endcapture %}
                      {{ imageUrl | img_tag }}
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <p class="grid-link__title">{{ 'home_page.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</p>
                  <p class="grid-link__meta">
                    <strong>$19.99</strong>
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
              {% assign index = index | plus: 1 %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% else %}
      <div class="grid__item">
        <p><em>{{ 'collections.general.no_matches' | t }}</em></p>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}

</div>

{% if paginate.pages > 1 %}
  <hr class="hr--clear">

  <div class="text-center">
    {% include 'pagination-custom' %}
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: Are you using linklists here?

Comment: @HymnZ Yes i am using linklist

Comment: Check in linklists section (`Admin Panel -> Online Store -> Navigation`) and see how it is configured. The code you have given here doesn't pertain to your issue.